# ios sqlite3 linking error

Tags: ios, sqlite, linker-errors

I'm starting to develop a small iOS application just for learning, and I'm attempting to use SQLite to store my app data. I'm using a simple CRUD operations, but when I compile the app (I want to try it in the device emulator) i've got this error

[image]

I've added libsqlite3.dylib to my project dependences.

[image]

I've tried many solutions, bun no one fix my problem.
Any idea about what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much

ps. The code are the following:

```
-(int) getPushCount {
int count = 0;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recived_push WHERE read = 1"];
    const char *getQuery = [query UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, getQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            count = sqlite_column_int(statement,0);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2.");
        NSLog(@"Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);

} else {
    NSLog(@"Oops! Something went terribly wrong...");
    NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    return nil;
}

NSLog(@"**Count: %d",count);

return count;
}
```

Comment: check your compiler source whether its having all .m file or not..if not add your .m files

Comment: @karthikeyan thx for your answer, but how can i check that? I'm so sorry... i'm really n00b on iOS and XCode :$

Comment: build phases->compiler source.that might be problem.i have faced problem like this and i solved by missing .m files

Comment: @karthikeyan hello again... it seems to be OK, all .m files seems to be included properly.

Comment: Just wondering, all the other sqlite calls appear to start with `sqlite3_`, but `sqlite_step` and `sqlite_column_int` do not. Is the 3 supposed to be in those as well?

Comment: @wrrzag i think u remove framework and clean derive data (windows -->Organizer-->projecs-->derivedata-->and all file move to trash ) and Then Clean project and add framework again and build project.

Comment: @Ilesh Not a bad idea when facing inexplicable Xcode errors, but in this case it's far easier: wrrzag just used the wrong function names (missing the `3` in those two functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code like this..

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW)  {
        count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You rulez! Thank you so much... :'D